# How to make sure wordpress and woocommerce plugins work on all configurations

Tags: plugin-development

So, we develop plugins that can be installed by end users. This usually works out okay, but in the past we've had some issues when after plugin installation there were issues with the website or issues with the plugin.

Here are some of the issues we experienced in the past:

1. Short opening and closing tags `<?=` weren't supported by the hosting provider and broke our plugin. So, after this issue with one user we decided to remove short tags from all of our plugins
2. Plugin failed when we had a 3rd party library included in our plugin but it was also included in another plugin which was causing conflict with identical name
3. One of our plugins added columns to admin part in woocommerce "Orders" page but other plugin on customer's website removed our columns. We had to decrease priority of our hook to make sure our plugin adds columns at the end.

In short, my question is: How to develop a resilient plugin and minimize failures. Is there a checklist, etc? Any automated tools? Anything? Hard to predict everything. Sometimes users' website have lots of crazy plugins installed.

Comment: Concerning item 1. To avoid a lot of similar problems, you should concider to use phpStorm with php code sniffer for WordPress. It simply doesn't allow short tags, for example.

Comment: Concerning item 2. You should use conditional statements with functions like class_exists()

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Thank you I will need to dig into code sniffers